# Доступ к окну-родителю в Qt

Tags: c++, qt, ооп

Имеется класс окна в Qt с кнопкой, который при нажатии на эту кнопку открывает другое окно:

`FrontView.hpp:`

```
namespace Ui {
    class FindDialog;
}

class FrontView : public QWidget {
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    FrontView();
    ~FrontView();
private:
    Ui::FrontView *ui;
    std::deque<int> data;
private slots:
    void on_pushButton_clicked();
};
```

`FrontView.cpp:`

```
FrontView::FrontView() : ui(new Ui::FrontView) {
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

void FrontView::on_pushButton_clicked() {
    auto dialog = new Dialog(this);
    dialog->show();
}
```

Окно, которое вызывается из FrontView `Dialog.hpp:`

```
namespace Ui {
    class FindDialog;
}

class Dialog : public QDialog {
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    Dialog(QWidget *);
    ~Dialog();
private:
    Ui::Dialog *ui;
};
```

`Dialog.cpp:`

```
Dialog::Dialog(QWidget *parent) : ui(new Ui::Dialog), QDialog(parent) {
    ui->setupUi(this);
}
```

Как мне получить доступ к ui класса FrontView? Реализовал такой "костыль": создал в классе Dialog поле `FrontView *mainWindow;` и в конструкторе инициализировал его классом `FrontView`. После этого, в `Dialog.cpp`, доступ, например, к `this->mainWindow->ui->pushButton`отлично работает. Но, как мне кажется, есть стандартные способы Qt для доступа к окну-родителю, ведь не просто так же конструктор имеет вид `Dialog(QWidget *parent)`? В общем, как правильно решить эту проблему?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно не хранить указатель на FrontView в классе Dialog, а при необходимости получать к нему доступ, используя метод `parent()`. Но это тоже тот ещё костыль, т.к. `parent()` возвращает `QWidget*`, и вам его придётся приводить к нужному типу:

```
if (qobject_cast<FrontView*>(parent()) != 0)
{
    /*Ваш код*/
}
```

А главное, что эти способы для доступа из `Dialog` к `FrontView::ui` требуют от вас писать объявление дружбы `friend class Dialog;` в описании класса FrontView. Это грубо нарушает принцип инкапсуляции реализации.
Стандартный способ для Qt - взаимодействие объектов с использованием сигналов-слотов. В вашем случае: пусть объект Dialog посылает сигналы и вы соединяете их с нужными слотами.
Пример кода:
FrontView.hpp:

```
namespace Ui {
    class FindDialog;
}

class FrontView : public QWidget {
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    FrontView();
    ~FrontView();
private:
    Ui::FrontView *ui;
    std::deque<int> data;

// Тестовый объект, принимающий сигнал (создайте его на форме в Дизайнере, тогда сможете обратиться к нему напрямую, как ui->myLabel, и этот указатель здесь не потребуется)
    QLabel* myLabel;

private slots:
    void on_pushButton_clicked();
    // Добавим слот-обработчик
    void testSlot();
};
```

FrontView.cpp:

```
FrontView::FrontView() : ui(new Ui::FrontView)
{
   ui->setupUi(this);

   // Создадим тестовый объект, принимающий сигнал
   myLabel = new QLabel(this);
   myLabel->setText("0");    
   ui->layout()->addWidget(myLabel);
}

void FrontView::on_pushButton_clicked() {
    auto dialog = new Dialog(this);
    // Инициализируем подключение
    connect(dialog, SIGNAL(testSignal()), this, SLOT(testSlot()));
    dialog->show();
}

// Реализация слота
void FrontView::testSlot()
{
    int num = myLabel->text().toInt();
    myLabel->setText(QString::number(++num));
}
```

Окно, которое вызывается из FrontView Dialog.hpp:

```
namespace Ui {
    class FindDialog;
}

class Dialog : public QDialog {
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    Dialog(QWidget *);
    ~Dialog();

// Опишем сигналы:
signals:
    void testSignal();

private:
    Ui::Dialog *ui;
};
```

Dialog.cpp:

```
Dialog::Dialog(QWidget *parent) : ui(new Ui::Dialog), QDialog(parent)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

// Создадим тестовую кнопку
    QPushButton* btn = new QPushButton(this);
    ui->layout()->addWidget(btn);
// Будем просто переизлучать сигнал от её нажатия
    connect(btn, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SIGNAL(testSignal())); 
}
```

Модифицировал ваш пример так, что при нажатии на кнопку в Dialog, увеличивается значение в QLabel FrontView.